# Date not working in ipython notebook but works on julia REPL

Tags: julia

```
using Dates
dateReported = map((x) -> string(x), df[:DateReported])
df[:DateOccurred] = map((x) -> if match(r"^((19|20)\d\d)(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])", x)!=nothing Date(x, DateFormat("yyyymmdd")) end, dateOccurred)
```

I am trying to change type of a dataframe column to Date from Int64.

The last statement returns an error

```
Date not defined
while loading In[18], in expression starting on line 1

 in anonymous at In[18]:1
 in map at /Users/ajkale/.julia/v0.3/DataArrays/src/datavector.jl:117
```

I am trying this in the ipython julia notebook. This works fine in the REPL though.

Comment: Sounds like your ipython might be using a different version of julia than what you're seeing at the REPL. Can you run `versioninfo()` in each to see if they match?

Comment: Both look the same to me

Answer (score 2):

Dates was not part of the Julia standard library in 0.3. Since then, Julia 0.4 and now 0.5 have this baked into the standard library.

http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/dates/